# Quote with no items - add to cart error

Tags: orders, quote, debug

I'm facing this strange issue on add to cart action:

sometime after I checkout (with a registered customer) correctly my order, if I try to purchase another item I got the following error:
`Call to a member function set final price() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php online 73`

I have debugged the code and found out that the issue is created by some old quotes associated with my user that are still active and have not items associated with it.

If I check the *problematic quote* in the Db it has `items_count = 0` any way `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::_assignProducts()`method try to load an item using null as Id :

```
 $product = $productCollection->getItemById($item->getProductId());
```

This triggers the above error.

Now the fast fix it to set to `is_active = 0` in all these quote, something like:

```
 UPDATE `sales_flat_quote` SET  `is_active` = 0 WHERE `is_active` = 1 AND `items_count`= 0 and customer_id is not null and customer_id <> 0
```

**Question**

Anyway, I would like to understand the following points:

1. Is it normal to have old quotes (also multiple for the same user) with 0 items and `is_active = 1`?
2. Is ok to delete all these quotes?  ( I have 10000+ quotes like this )

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If it is throwing for all the customers then you can delete **sales_flat_quote_item** table. If this happens only for the particular customer then do the following thing. In this case, all the quotes won't be deleted.

1. Get the customer id from **sales_flat_quote_address(column name: customer_id)** table. Here you can get the specific quote id(column name in table is quote_id) which is causing the problem.

> Example: SELECT quote_id FROM sales_flat_quote_address where
> customer_id=23423

2. Now, go to **sales_flat_quote_item** then delete the particular records which is causing the problem.

> Example: DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote_item WHERE quote_id=43535